# How to handle an array of pointers in Objective-C

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, pointers

I figured out the answer to this question, but I couldn't find the solution on here, so posting it for posterity.

So, in Objective-C, how do you create an object out of a pointer in order to store it in objective-c collections (NSArray, NSDictionary, NSSet, etc) without reverting to regular C?

Comment: Posterity ... and reputation!  ;)

Comment: Heh yeah I guess.  I don't have a lot of free time to answer others' questions, but when I come across an interesting answer on my own, I like to give back.

Comment: Hey Tim, I'd like to keep the "C" tag.  I know the question is about objective-c, but it's also about, specifically, a replacement for a "C" answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSValue *pointerObject = [NSValue valueWithPointer:aPointer];
```

This will wrap the pointer in an NSValue.  To get it back out later use NSValue's instance method (pointerValue:)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to define a class that has methods that access/manipulate the contents of the pointer, then add instances of that to the array.

Don't bother subclassing NSValue as it really adds nothing to the solution.

Something like:

```
@interface FooPtr:NSObject
{
    void *foo;
}

+ fooPtrWithFoo: (void *) aFoo;

.... methods here ...
@end
```

I specifically chose an opaque (void *) as that tells the client "don't touch my innnards directly".  In the implementation, do something like `#define FOOPTR(foo) ((Foo *) foo)`  Then you can `FOOPTR(foo)->bar;` as needed in your various methods.

Doing it this way also makes it trivial to add Objective-C specific logic on top of the underlying datatype.  Sorting is just a matter of implementing the right method.  Hashing/Dictionary entries can now be hashed on foo's contents, etc...